# addclass function not working in firefox and ie

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

here is my code for adding a class on a dropdown on click of a button.

```
$('#search_select1').addClass('borderClass');
```

and this is css class

```
.borderClass{
   -webkit-opacity: 0.25;
  -moz-opacity: 0.25;
  opacity: 0.25;
-webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 3s ease;
  transition: all 3s ease;
}
```

its working fine on google chrome but this class is not getting add in firefox and ie. Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: addClass is working but css property are not working

Comment: Works fine on Firefox 24 with Linux Mint.

Comment: I'm using firefox it is working to me

Comment: see the developer console to check whether the add class function is working for you or not , as it seems , it is working , and also the property you have set is browser specific

Comment: Works fine problem must be somewhere else http://jsbin.com/urEVazo/1/edit

Comment: @Salim yes this may also be the reason. So what I am suppose to do now so that it start working on firefox and IE too?

Comment: In the future, please tag your questions correctly. This problem has nothing to do with `PHP` (tag removed), it is solely a client-side problem. Whether it’s PHP that might assemble your HTML code on the server, or it’s knitted by your Grandma, does absolutely not matter here.

Comment: You sample code works here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/zn65a/; what is the element #search_select1 ?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward its working for me now as i have change order of addclass attribute and disable attribute but now removeclass attribute is not working j110('#search_select1').removeClass('borderClass'); j110('#search_select1').select2("enable", true);

Comment: You are using select2, can you provide a real demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward http://jsfiddle.net/nmangla/vBF7S/12/ check out the link. add and remove class attribute is not working

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward while http://jsfiddle.net/nmangla/vBF7S/2/ here add and remove class working fine at both browsers

Answer (score 2):

Please insert your code between

`$(document).ready(function(){   });`

For Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// other code

    $(document).ready(function(){ 
       $('#search_select1').addClass('borderClass');
    });

});
```

it's work , I am sure.

Answer (score 1):

11:58:29.264 ReferenceError: `fun_select` is not defined show:1

11:58:35.849 ReferenceError: `clear_selection` is not defined

Somehow you aren't loading your functions properly.

If the targets are static, why not just try this?

**HTML**

```
<input type = 'button' value = 'Apply CSS' id="fun_select" />
<input type = 'button' value = 'Remove CSS' id="remove" />
```

**JS:**

```
$('#fun_select').on('click', function() {
    $('#search_select1').addClass('borderClass');
});

$('#remove').on('click', function() {
    $('#search_select1').removeClass('borderClass');
});
```

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/vBF7S/13/